Black blob-like alien jumps onto a scientist's face
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me identify what this scene is from. I really only remember one big scene from this when I was a kid. This would have been from around 1985 or so, but the movie/show was older than that. It was black-and-white and I'm guessing from the 50s or 60s.
The one scene I remember was of at least one scientist in a lab coat in front of a glass wall containing a small black blob-like creature about the size and shape of a large hand. A rectangular panel opens in the glass wall and the creature falls onto the panel and then I remember it jumping on the scientist's face. Very reminiscent of the face-hugger scene from Alien. Unfortunately that's all I really remember. I'm assuming it was a science fiction film or some sort, but it's possible it could have been an episode from a tv show.

That could be the "Outer Limits" episode "Corpus Earthling", (1963).  The episode is available on Hulu.

Parasitic advance guard from outer space strive to kill a physician,
  the only human who can hear them. Instead the physician believes he's
  gone insane, because he first heard the aliens right after suffering a
  concussion in a lab explosion. His wife, the laboratory's assistant,
  comforts him, while the lab's geologist is targeted for takeover by
  the parasites.




That IS a scene from Corpus Earthling, one of the Outer Limits episodes, and Dr. Temple is about to be taken over by this life form.  These "two black crystalline rocks" (as the narrator says at the end) turned up in Temple's lab, and were unidentifiable.  They communicated telepathically, but the boyfriend (Robert Culp) of Temple's lab assistant was able to hear them after sustaining a head injury from an explosion in the lab.  He hears their plan to dominate Earth, and you need to watch the rest.

How does this differ from the previous (accepted) answer by Will Feldman?
